# How to use google custom search for discord.js with their js api?

Tags: discord.js, google-custom-search

I need to make a command that searches my google custom search for a google website. I already have the custom-search ID and key.

I've tried using a few of the google npm nodes, but nothing gave me the result I was looking for, most are for image queries.

This is from google

```js
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JSON Custom Search API Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
      function hndlr(response) {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
        var item = response.items[i];
        // in production code, item.htmlTitle should have the HTML entities escaped.
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<br>" + item.htmlTitle;
      }
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=YOUR-KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=cars&callback=hndlr">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Like I said, I want to use it for d.js for a custom-search command...just don't understand much on it. While i'm still new, I've coded my own bot so i'm not extremely new on it, this part is just leaving me stumped.

Comment: This example is for javascript running in a web browser. In the case of discord.js, you are running node.js. You can make the REST queries using the `fetch()` method inside your code